# Which is always true for a twice Differentiable function with certain properties?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I tried to do this by constructing a function that satisfies the given conditions but i did not reach anywhere. And i can't think of any theoretical way of doing it.

I always find it difficult to approach this kind of question.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's just think about the function.
On $[-1,0]$, it has a mean rate equals to $1$. The mean value theorem says there exists $c\in (-1,0)$ for which $f'(c) = 1$.

Now, look at $f'$ on $[c,1/2]$. It has a mean rate of $0$. The mean value theorem now says that there exists $d \in (c,1/2)$ for wich $(f')'(d) = 0$.

Okay, that seems to be all we can know about $f$ with the assumptions.

Now, look at the questions : we have shown that the two first are true. Are the two others false? You have to find a counter-example. I suggest you to just draw a picture to convice yourself.